# Correct function to use in Excel with "word" variables

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I have a column header saying `Home City` (without the quotation marks). However, I want to assign that Home City to a Province (which is equivalent to a State in America). I don't think the `IF` function would be correct to use here though...

So for example if the Home City is `Cape Town`, and I have another column called `Province`, I want a function that says if `Home City = Cape Town`, then in the province column, the words `Western Cape` should be reflected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are going to have is the macro or function will not know what province goes with what city unless you tell it. By the time you develop anything to do that, you will have been able to add them manually.

To add them manually, I would use a `pick from list` in the province column if there are only 9 to choose from.

1. Make the list of provinces in a range which can be hidden or is out
   of sight.
2. Select all the cells in the Province column.
3. Go to the Data tab then Data Validation.
4. On the Settings tab, select List from the Allow drop-down list.
5. In the Source text box, enter the range of the list you made or use
   the selector tool.
6. Select the In-cell Dropdown check box.
7. Click OK.

[image]

You will now have a pick from list in each of the cells in the column for provinces.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a good solution. I would vote you up if I could. Prevents me by mistake **not** putting a province in the province column.

Comment: May not let you up-vote, but you should be able to accept it as your answer if you want.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know what words go in the 'Province' column?  I assume you have a list somewhere.

If so, what you want is the [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) function.  This looks at a piece of data (the value in the 'Home City' cell), finds that value in the first column of a list and then retrieves a value from another column in that list and puts it in the cell you want.

Comment: Thanks - will try it now. Yes, there are only 9 provinces, however, there are many more home cities. What I am planning to do to save time is to associate the more common cities in my dataset with their respective provinces, so I don't have to manually look at every home city.